# Equivalent of UncaughtExceptionHandler of java in C# for UWP Apps

Tags: c#, uwp, unhandled-exception, uncaught-exception, uncaughtexceptionhandler

In java we have Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler for handling the unhandled exceptions. How can I handle the unhandleded exception in C# UWP.

I am unable to use the AppDomain as it is not supported. Also, there are some references around Assemblies. Is there any example or document I can refer to ?

Thank you

Comment: Does this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Application#Windows_UI_Xaml_Application_UnhandledException work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since I am new with C#, I am finding it hard to implement using the details in that documentation. I found one link as follows, but that is not usable for UWP. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/… An equivalent of the above documented example will be very helpful for me.

If you create a new blank UWP project, you will find the `App.xaml.cs` file. Open it and register the `UnhandledException` event for your app like the following:

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
    /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
    /// </summary>
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
        this.UnhandledException += App_UnhandledException;
    }

    private void App_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO:
    }
....
}
```

[image]

Since you said that you're new with c#, what you need to do is to learn some [c# basic technology](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/) at first. For example, [How to: Subscribe to and Unsubscribe from Events (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are looking for [UnhandledException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Application#Windows_UI_Xaml_Application_UnhandledException)

You can subscribe the `OnUnhandledException` event and if the `UnhandledException` event handler sets the `Handled` property of the event arguments to `true`, then in most cases the app will not be terminated.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. This is exactly the same one I am looking for. But I was looking for an example on how to use the same from my app. Since I am new with C#, I am finding it hard to implement using the details in that documentation. I found one link as follows, but that is not usable for UWP. 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx

An equivalent of the above documented example will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Xavier beat me to it.. Check his answer below :)